# Determining Region of Convergence for the Laurent Series of $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)(z^2 + 1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Determine the region of convergence for the Laurent series $$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z^2 + 1)} = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n (z-1)^n$$

I know that the series can not converge at $z = 1$ and $z = \pm i$, as those are singularities of the function. However I'm not sure how to determine the region of convergence more precisely than that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you mark the three singularities (simple poles, in this case) on the complex plane, what is the radius of the largest circle centred at $z=1$ within which the function is analytic (excluding $z=1$, of course)? That will give you the inner region of convergence. The outer region (where the series expansion is different, I.e. has different coefficients $a_n$) is then straightforwardly identified.

Comment: So the the series does not converge for any points within this circle? Also, I'm assuming the series will converge for any points outside the circle? Although I don't know how to prove it mathematically. I would usually use the ratio test, but the coefficients $a_n$ are unknown.

Comment: There are two Laurent series expansions of the type you wrote in the question, each converging within an annulus centred at $z=1$. You can simply identify such annuli of convergence by looking at the complex plane where you will have marked the three singularities. You can see that the inner annulus is actually a circle, the largest circle centred at $z=1$ you can draw without hitting either or both of the other singularities. What is the radius of that circle? I'll leave it to you to answer.
The other annulus, where, again, the series has different coefficients $a_n$, is the outer region.

Comment: Regarding the other remark you made, you can actually calculate the coefficients of the two series and determine the regions of convergence through geometric series, but it sounds like you have not studied that yet.

Comment: In the comment above, which I cannot edit apparently, the inner annulus is a (punctured) disk, not a "circle" as I wrote. The circle is the boundary of that disk. I trust the meaning was clear though.

Comment: Just searched for you.  I was replying to you at the post you deleted, to let you know I did *not downvote your post*.  In any case, I did upvote this post.  I don't understand the downvote at the other post, and after your edit, I was prepared to upvote your post.   Some downvotes make no sense.  I don't think the downvote cast on your other question was legitimate.  So, welcome!  Hope to see you around this site! ;-)

Comment: I upvoted this post too. Dont be discouraged by the downvotes on the other post...Welcome on MSE.

Comment: Ok, I'll put this story behind, but, forgive me, you guys who are moderators, thus competent, should prevent absurd downvotes like that one, or force the downvoter to explain their action. And I have no sense of superiority as it was implied in a comment on the other question. Quite the opposite, I'd like to help users who genuinely want to learn, if I may.

Comment: @user319665 I'm still somewhat confused. This was given as an exam problem, and  apparently the series does **not** converge for any points inside the inner circle, for instance the point $1 + i$. Also, it should be possible to determine the outer region of convergence without calculating any coefficients $a_n$ I believe?

Comment: I can see that and I'm sorry, and the only explanation I have is that you typed a different $f(z)$ from the exam's. I could show you that the series $\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=-1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left[\frac{1}{(1-i)^{n+2}}-\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n+2}}\right](z-1)^n$ converges to $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z^2+1)}$ at all $z$ of the punctured disk $0\lt |z-1| \lt\sqrt{2}$ (the famous radius, Pythagoras' theorem I unsuccessfully tried to have you apply). $z=1+i$ is inside that disk because the distance of that point from $z=1$ is less than $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The outer region? It's the annulus $|z-1|\gt ....$ As I stressed various times above, the series there has different coefficients from the one I showed you above. I'm afraid I don't know how else I can help you.

Comment: One last example, let's see if it makes any difference. Consider $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2i)(z+i)}$ and let's find the regions of convergence to $f(z)$ of Laurent series of the type $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$. There are three regions, each with its own LS centered at $z=1$. Just by looking at the three singularities on the complex plane and using Pythagoras' theorem you can tell that the innermost r. is the punctured disk $0\lt |z-1| \lt \sqrt{2}$, the central r. is the annulus $\sqrt{2} \lt |z-1| \lt \sqrt{5}$ and the external r. is $|z-1| \gt \sqrt{5}$.